# Why are Linked Lists Reversed?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, data-structures, linked-list, traversal

**Why are Linked Lists Reversed?**

I have been listening to a lot of Software Engineers that talk about reversing Linked Lists. What is the use of reversing a linked list? What are the advantages of doing so rather than traversing backwards?

- Why are they used in technical interviews?
- What is the use besides technical interviews?

Comment: I do not think there is a specific use case for reversing a linked list other than it being a common question asked in software developer interviews.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reversing a linked list comes up every now and then in real life.

Most recently I did that while implementing a lock-free multi-producer single-consumer work queue.  Stacks are the simplest lock-free data structure to implement, and the implementation is a singly-linked list, so my multiple producers would push new work onto a lock free stack.

The single consumer can then get the whole stack at once, but then has to reverse it to make a queue of tasks in the correct order.

That said...   you're probably asking the wrong question.  The task of reversing a linked list is one of the easiest data structure manipulations you can do.  If you're being taught to do it, then it's just an early lesson on the long road to really understanding programming.  If you're being asked about it in an interview, then the interviewer wants to know if you might be programmer who can design, implement, and maintain data structures, or if you can just copy and modify answers from StackOverflow, and glue together things you don't understand.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there are linked Lists aswell as double linked lists. When you are usind double linked lists, every node has a pointer to the next and the previous node so that it is easy to traverse backwards. When the list is "only linked" the nodes only have a "next-reference" so you won't be able to traverse backwards.
I hope that answered the question properly

Comment: Thank you, but sadly that doesn't answer my question. In other words, why is it done and in what instance is it used?

Comment: @RandomProgrammer It does partially answer the question, giving an example for why it's done: If you want to traverse backwards (like you mention in your question) but *can't* (because it's a singly linked list). In such a case, you can reverse first and then traverse forwards, equivalent to the impossible direct backwards traversal.

Answer (score 0):

It is very common to reverse lists that are the result of a recursive function. Consider a `map` function

```
   fn map (fun, lst) =
        local fn mp (in, out) = 
             if null(in)
             then out
             else mp(tail(in), fun(head(in)) :: out)
        return reverse(mp(lst, nil))
```

It reverses the result of the inner function to restore the result order to the order of the input list.

There are more efficient ways to do this if your language supports mutation, i.e., by keeping a pointer to the last pair in the list and appending a pair on every call to the inner function.